# Subject-dependent inversion

Tags: inversion, subjects, complements

**In front of him opens a magnificent view on mountains.**

Is such a subject-dependent inversion possible? Or should I use

**there opens a magnificent view on mountains in front of him**?

Comment: Do you mean subject-verb inversion?

Comment: Yes, that's another way to call it. **In front of him** is a dependent of the verb **open** and **a magnificent view on mountains** is a subject. Will the sentence be correct if i swap their places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Switching the subject and predicate like that can be acceptable (though stylized)

To place the subject after the verb and the prepositional phrase before it is comprehendible but very stylized. You will often see this kind of structure in scripts for film and television as descriptions for a scene.

A writer/speaker might adopt the same structure to make what they are describing sound more dramatic because the phrasing is so strongly associated with the arts.

In more typical speech and writing, though, inverting the subject and predicate like that would seem a little weird.